# the keystore has been tampered with or the password is incorrect

Tags: android

I have just configured eclipse with the Android SDK plus the ADT plugin. Im new to Android and when i create a new project I get this popup error that says "Your project contains error(s),please fix them before running your project. I have tried to clean my project but the error still persists. In the problems window, I get the following error:java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect. I dont understand, I am not using any google maps certificate, its just a new project that should display helloworld. Someone please help, I am new to android and would just like to have atleast a helloworld running.

Answer (score 0):

Lets check what keystore you are using.

In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build.

Do you have a custom debug keystore set?

Next, if you are already using the default keystore, make sure it exists in the folder.  You might also try downloading a new default keystore to replace it.

Comment: I dont have a custom debug keystore set. The default keystore is debug.keystore. Do you mean the debug.keystore should exist in the project folder? mine is in C:\Users\John\.android\debug.keystore. Where can i download it? Thanx

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have an API Key for Maps using a custom keystore and I'm pointing to that keystore in preferences->custom keystore but it gives me the above message but there's no field to enter password.